# xpath Query for xpath extractor of Jmeter

Tags: xpath, extractor

Can someone please provide me the xml query for retrieving the value of sessionId from the below response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns2:createUserResponse xmlns:ns2="http://www.musicthp.com"     
                    isNewUser="false"
                    profileId="32109" 
                    sessionId="ryIlb+E5yj7FReA2w96uag=="
                    success="true">
<duration>316</duration>
</ns2:createUserResponse>
```

I tried using /ns2:createUserResponse/@sessionId and seems its not returning anything.
I want to use this query in the XPATH extractor of jmeter. 
My requirement: I need to retrieve sessionId value using xpath extractor and use that value in the successive requests.

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you set JMeter to use namespaces?

JMeter has been reported to have problems with namespaces. If fiddling with settings won't help, here is a workaround for the root element

```
/*/@sessionId
```

Workaround for any element in a namespace is to use `*[local-name() = 'element']` instead of `prefix:element`

Comment: not sure why, it keeps returning me "duration value" which is 316 in my response.

Comment: @manoj desai: I have the xpath extractor with use Namespaces checked, i even tried using use Tidy option, i am still not able to get sessionId value with /*/@sessionId

Comment: IT WORKED PERFECTLY FINE. THANKS JASSO. I was doing something wrong which i corrected now.